# Criteria API: use greaterThan on a char column

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

I have to rebuild a query, except for one line everything works fine.

Here the line in sql:

```
... 
AND someId > '0'
...
```

someId is a char-field that mostly contains numbers, but sometimes trailing characters. 
My criteria-part of that looks like this:

```
cb.greaterThan(myClass.get(MyClass_.someId), 0)
```

which results in

```
... 
AND someId > 0 
...
```

(regard the missing ')

This screws up the query as I can't use the greaterThan on a char-column.

What I need are all someIds that are just made of numbers and do not contain any letters.

I tried adding a

```
cb.function("isNumeric", Boolean.class, myClass.get(MyClass_.someId))
```

to my where-clauses, but the cb.and doesnt like that. :)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To answer myself:

I tweaked the isNumeric-thing to this

```
c.equal(cb.function("isNumeric", Boolean.class, myClass.get(MyClass_.someId)), 1)
```

and this works fine.